# FXMLLoader doesn't find.fxml file inside of resources

Tags: java, javafx

My `FXMLLoader` doesn't seem to find my fxml-file which is located in the resources folder.

I'm using gradle to run my project. Since the structure is already give, I've created a new Scene and am now trying to load it.

**Main:**

```java
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LoginWindow.fxml"));

            Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
            // ignore for the time being
        }
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.zhaw.pm2.SportHub.controller.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Hallo Welt" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The error message is as follows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

In theory this should work just fine but it doesn't. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: `LoginController.java` is in a package called controller and the class is currently empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Parent root;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginWindow.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: No, both my main and fxml file are in its root folder. Only the `LoginController` is inside a package.

Comment: check the edit of the answer :)